# Please what is the difference between [attribute~=value] and [attribute*=value]

Tags: css, attributes

cannot find the difference between these two selectors. Both seem to do the same thing i.e select tags based on a specific attribute value containing a given string.

For [attribute~=value] : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp

For [attribute*=value] : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp

Comment: One is a squiggly, and one is an asterisk.  (Couldn't resist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one (`[attribute~=value]`) is a whitespace-separated search...

```
<!-- Would match -->
<div class="value another"></div>
```

...and the second (`[attribute*=value]`) is a substring search...

```
<!-- Would match -->
<div class="a_value"></div>
```

W3Schools doesn't appear to make this distinction very clear. Use a [better resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Thanks for that Alex. Yea i will have to do a more broad search next time but i thought i should ask here too because someone would be able to explain this very simply (such as yourself) in a way that would make sense to anyone.

Comment: @Epik Glad you could understand it.

Answer (score 1):

[attribute~="value"] selects elements that contain a given word delimited by spaces while [attribute*="value"] selects elements that contain the given substring.

For example, [data-test~="value"] would not match on the below div while [data-test*="value"] would.

```
<div data-test="my values go here"></div>
```